# Is it possible/should I solve for $y$ in this equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble understanding this question from my book:

"$b)$ Find the solution of the differential equation in Example $4$ when $\ln c_1$ is used as the constant of integration on the *left-hand* side in the solution and $4 \ln c_1$ is replaced by $\ln c$. Then solve the same initial-value problems in part $(a)$."

The original DE from example $4$ is $$(e^{2y}-y) \cos x \dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^y \sin 2x, y(0)=0$$

The book solved it to $$e^y + ye^{-y}+e^{-y}=-2 \cos x + C$$

The initial conditions in part $(a)$ were $y(0)=2, y(0)=-2$, and $y(\dfrac 14)=1$

Now following the directions concerning the constant, I rewrote the solution as

$$e^y + ye^{-y}+e^{-y} + \ln c_1=-2 \cos x$$

However, I do not see what useful manipulation would lead to a $4 \ln c_1$. The closest thing to $4$ is one of the initial conditions $y(\dfrac 14)=1$, but I don't see how that helps since we will just end up with a $\cos \dfrac 14$

Comment: I wonder if the answer in the back of the book has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh I'm sorry, that answer is part of the answer to part a, which deals with a different DE. However, I am still not sure where the $4\ln c_1$ comes from. I have edited the question